# Gradle sync failed: No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1

Tags: android, build.gradle, android-studio-3.6

I've tried several methods to resolve this problem but it has all failed. I have uninstalled and removed all files before reinstalling with no avail.

Below is an image of the error:

[image: click here for android studio image.]

Comment: Please render errors in text here, rather than presenting them as images. For more information, read: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.